# Location Services and Call Description status bar of iOS causes to appear black status bar. How to fix it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, uistatusbar

When Other Applications uses Location services iOS status bar example given below.
[image]

It Causes a black status bar above and it causes some problem on network operations such as sending data to the server / Job request are not working when the black status bar appear only. See Below Screenshot.
[image]
Sometimes it causes on below screen as well.
[image]

When Black bar appears on the screen it's not going away till closes the app and re open it. It causing major functionalities of this app.

Answer (score 0):

Select viewcontroller->view and from size inspector uncheck "Safe Area Relative Margins". Then you will have the safe area removed. I think it will solve your black bar issue.
[Check this for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwUZ9.png)

Thanks

Comment: I did the same but still I am having the issue.